# How to build tensorflow c++ code use a custom toolchain of bazel?

Tags: c++, tensorflow, bazel

I want to use bazel to cross-compile TensorFlow's C ++ code and get arm executable version, run it on Arm architecture machine.

Follow the wiki https://github.com/bazelbuild/bazel/wiki/Building-with-a-custom-toolchain, I modify some code and I push the code to [mygithub:bazel_toolchain](https://github.com/kingcong/bazel_toolchain).

Then I place bazel_toolchain directory in the file tensorflow/bazel_toolchain inside a clone of the TensorFlow github repository

Now the tree is /root/tensorflow_master/tensorflow/bazel_toochain

I add hello.cc code as below:

**hello.cc code:**

```
 #include "tensorflow/cc/client/client_session.h"
 #include "tensorflow/cc/ops/standard_ops.h"
 #include "tensorflow/core/framework/tensor.h"

 int main() {
   using namespace tensorflow;
   using namespace tensorflow::ops;
   Scope root = Scope::NewRootScope();
   // Matrix A = [3 2; -1 0]
   auto A = Const(root, { {3.f, 2.f}, {-1.f, 0.f} });
   // Vector b = [3 5]
   auto b = Const(root, { {3.f, 5.f} });
   // v = Ab^T
   auto v = MatMul(root.WithOpName("v"), A, b, MatMul::TransposeB(true));
   std::vector<Tensor> outputs;
   ClientSession session(root);
   // Run and fetch v
   TF_CHECK_OK(session.Run({v}, &outputs));
   // Expect outputs[0] == [19; -3]
   LOG(INFO) << outputs[0].matrix<float>();
   return 0;
}
```

**BUILD file as below:**

```
filegroup(
 name = "srcs",
 srcs = glob(["**"]),
 visibility = ["//tensorflow/bazel_toolchain:__pkg__"],
)

cc_binary(
 name = "hello",
 srcs = ["hello.cc"],
 deps = [
    "//tensorflow/cc:cc_ops",
    "//tensorflow/cc:client_session",
    "//tensorflow/core:tensorflow",
 ],
 )
```

when I run below command on /root/tensorflow_master/ directory,

```
 bazel build --crosstool_top=//tensorflow/bazel_toolchain/tools/arm_compiler:toolchain --cpu=armeabi-v7a 
 //tensorflow/bazel_toolchain:hello
```

it notices

```
tensorflow-master/tensorflow/bazel_toolchain/tools/arm_compiler/BUILD:46:1: no such package '@org_linaro_components_toolchain_gcc_5_3_1//': The repository could not be resolved and referenced by '//tensorflow/bazel_toolchain/tools/arm_compiler:linaro_linux_linker_files'.
```

ERROR: Analysis of target '//tensorflow/bazel_toolchain:hello' failed; build aborted

What should I do? Thanks a lot!

Answer (score -1):

The build file you shared is not correct, there is `)` after `srcs` that effectively closes `cc_binary`, so `deps` are not an attribute on `cc_binary` but a declaration of a variable in the BUILD file (I think). Move `deps` into cc_binary.

The error message is however unrelated to above. Can you share the command line you use to build hello-world? Do you use --crosstool_top to use your custom crosstool? Can you edit your question to add content of your WORKSPACE file?

Comment: I put my code to [github](https://github.com/kingcong/bazel_toolchain),  I only want to cross-compile tensorflow c++ code in order to run it on arm machine.  Because I am not familar to use of bazel, this question bothered me for a long time. Thanks for your help again!

Comment: I didn't have time to look at your repo yet, but you're not the first person to build tensorflow on arm, search for messages about this on bazel-discuss google group and ask people that sucessfully built it. I definitely helped at least 2 other folks, maybe more.

Comment: OK, I will find a solution from other channels. Thank you very much for your help!